# Why defined function only works when set equal to a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on the kaggle titanic problem in python and so far I've created multiple defined functions to tidy and alter my data for the model and had no problem implementing it into a pipeline (where the returned values is a dataframe). However, I've been having issues with creating a OHE function.

The below OHE_cat function is spitting back the correct dataframe if I preform the same code outside of the function and I've been creating print (df.columns/index) after every step and I can see that the function itself is working through the entire process.

The main issue I'm having is that the function only works if I set *OHE_test = OHE_cat(OHE_test)*. Normally for my other functions I could just set OHE_cat(OHE_test) and it would adjust the test_df according to the function. However, I'm not sure why this can't work for this function.

```
def OHE_cat (df):
    OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
    cat_col = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'object']
    OH_cols_train = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.fit_transform(df[cat_col]))
    OH_cols_train.index = df.index
    df = pd.concat([df, OH_cols_train], axis=1)
    df.drop(cat_col, axis=1, inplace = True)
    return df

OHE_test = bin_test.copy()
OHE_test = OHE_cat(OHE_test)

print (OHE_test.columns)
OHE_test.head()
```

Wanted (only achived with: OHE_test = OHE_cat(OHE_test))

```
Pclass  Survived    train   Age_was_missing Embarked_was_missing    Fare_was_missing    Ticket_was_missing  Deck_was_missing    0   1   ... 15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
PassengerId                                                                                 
1   3.0 0.0 1.0 False   False   False   False   True    0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
2   1.0 1.0 1.0 False   False   False   False   False   0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
3   3.0 1.0 1.0 False   False   False   False   True    0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
4   1.0 1.0 1.0 False   False   False   True    False   0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
5   3.0 0.0 1.0 False   False   False   True    True    0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Got: (with only OHE_cat(OHE_test)

```
Age Embarked    Fare    Pclass  Sex Survived    Ticket  train   Related Title   Deck    Age_was_missing Embarked_was_missing    Fare_was_missing    Ticket_was_missing  Deck_was_missing
PassengerId                                                             
1   Early   S   Low 3.0 male    0.0 Low 1.0 Duo M   Safer   False   False   False   False   True
2   Mid C   High    1.0 female  1.0 High    1.0 Duo MF  Less    False   False   False   False   False
3   Early   S   Low 3.0 female  1.0 Mid 1.0 Solo    NF  Safer   False   False   False   False   True
4   Mid S   High    1.0 female  1.0 Mid 1.0 Duo MF  Less    False   False   False   True    False
5   Mid S   Low 3.0 male    0.0 Mid 1.0 Solo    M   Safer   False   False   False   True    True
```

The main reason I want it to work without setting it to *OHE_test = OHE_cat(OHE_test)* is because it doesn't seem to work with my pipeline below, and that seems only possible if it's OHE_cat(OHE_test)

```
def pp_pipeline(df):
    (df.pipe(feature_engineering)
    .pipe(missing_data)
    .pipe(fare_age_bins)
    .pipe(OHE_cat))
    return df
```

Comment: The function takes an argument and returns something. It doesn’t modify what you give it so you have to store the returned object if you want to use it

Comment: Change your pipeline to `df = (df.pipe(...).pipe(...)` pipe returns a new object, `df` doesn't change there, you need to reassign it.

Comment: If you know which df to do the operation on beforehand, and you want inplace modification, then you can use the `global` keyword with the name of your df inside the function.

Comment: Glad to be of help.